# Checking if something is not in multiple lists - how to make it more elegant

Tags: python, arrays, list, boolean

What works:

```
a = ["0"]
b = ["1"]
c = ["2"]
d = ["3"]
if (not "0" in a) and (not "0" in b) and (not "0" in c) and (not "0" in 
d):
  print "you don't want this to be printing"
```

What I've tried and doesn't work:

```
if not "0" in (a and b and c and d):
  print ""

if not "0" in a, b, c, d:
  print ""
```

What could I use to avoid the inelegance of my first statement that works, given that the lists must be separate and I have many of them?

Answer (score 1):

Put everything into a list then use `all`:

```
lists = [a, b, c, d]
if all("0" not in x for x in lists):
    print("you don't want this to be printing")
```

But it's probably faster (and clearer) to use Demorgan's law and negate:

```
lists = [a, b, c, d]
if not any("0" in x for x in lists):
    print("you don't want this to be printing")
```

Even faster (and clearest):

```
if "0" not in set().union(a, b, c, d):
    print("you don't want this to be printing")
```

Answer (score 1):

why not simple join all list and do check:

```
if "0" not in a + b + c + d:
    print("you don't want this to be printing")
```

and the solution more fast the `set` for mediun size lists, here some test for perfomance:

```
In [1]: from random import randint
   ...: a = [str(randint(1, 1000)) for _ in range(500)]
   ...: b = [str(randint(1, 1000)) for _ in range(500)]
   ...: c = [str(randint(1, 1000)) for _ in range(500)]
   ...: d = [str(randint(1, 1000)) for _ in range(500)]
   ...: 

In [2]: %timeit "0" not in a + b + c + d
30.2 µs ± 265 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit "0" not in set().union(a, b, c, d)
48.5 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

but the solution using `set` saved memory, because `a + b + c + d` generate new big list.

Comment: In this case, there aren't any collisions and the sizes of the lists are small. The speed really depends on the data itself. For a pathalogical example, consider `a` being a list of 1000000000 `"1"`'s. Your suggestion may cause OOM! (In *that* scenario, #2 in my examples gives the best memory efficiency.)

Comment: Essentially, *you cannot measure performance without knowing the structure of the data itself.*

Comment: @MateenUlhaq thank you for comment, about memory you're right. For medium-sized lists i edit the answer. For big data not think both solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not any(map(lambda x: "0" in x, [a, b, c, d])):
    print "you don't want this to be printing"
```

This is mapping a list of your lists to the lambda function you were repeating for each list, `"0" in x`, x being the lambda parameter, or list.

Comment: Please add some textual description to your answer ... we are human beings.